# Prevent Google from listing all pages as video results just because the header uses a video

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, video

I have embedded a `<video>` in the header of a website. It is only used for cosmetic reasons and is present on almost all sub pages.

Now I noticed that whenever I enter a search term in Google's Everything Search, some of the links to my page (including the actual landing page) are displayed as a video result, with the 12-second video thumbnail included.

Of course that doesn't fit the page's content at all, since the video is far from a core element on this page.

How can I prevent Google from showing my results this way?
Other questions only seem to deal with *adding* a video, whilst I want mine removed.

Comment: Just to be sure: You *don’t* have [structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video) for this video, right? (could be added automatically by a CMS, for example)

Comment: @unor I am using a CMS, but I rechecked my source and could not find anything there. I also used Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) but it says that 0 items are present on the page.

Comment: What was the solution? Do you still have the problem now?Please answer your own question if it solved.

Comment: I haven't solved this issue but search ranking took over and moved the unwanted results to a later page. I would be happy if someone ever finds this post and an answer to the problem.